# Node modules installed but not available

Tags: 14.04, command-line, nodejs

I am new to Linux environment and right now learning node.js

Following the tutorial i installed node module express globally as shown in below screenshot

[image]

But when i am trying to use express in terminal it says express is not installed.

[image]

Please note that i have installed from nvm

Thanks

Comment: What tutorial?  You didn't install via apt-get?

Comment: it was from Lynda essentials of node.js

Comment: Should "installed not from nvm" be "installed node from nvm"? Based on your screenshots, it looks like that's the case. While the answer below is definitely correct, you'll also want to make sure that the command `which node` returns a directory.

Comment: oh sorry you are right its installed from nvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing express globally generally isn't a good idea, the way most node modules work is by being installed on a per-repo basis so anyone can recreate the environment by running `npm install`.

Thus the [recommended way](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html) to install express is to run `npm install express --save`, which will not only download the module but also create an entry in the project's package.json.

Express is then never run directly from the command line but instead added using `require()` in either app.js or a file run by it. An example for how to do this is express' official [Hello World](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html).